# Getting Error 403 when reading from web vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net, webclient, http-status-code-403

I have this code:

```
Dim address As String = "mywebsite"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim webresult As String = (client.DownloadString(address))
```

But the last line gives an error 403. I made the PHP script and it should not do this. The PHP is

```
<?php

$pass="test";

if ($pass==$_GET['password']){
echo "Correct!";
} else {
echo "Incorrect!";
}
```

Edit: I can access it via web browsers with no problem

Comment: Check the permissions on the PHP file.

Comment: @lxg its 755, read is always allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had such an issue while working in PHP. Some server configurations reject a web-request with a non-existant user-agent.

To set a user agent, do:

```
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "myUserAgentString";
```

Comment: Ancient question, but this was actually the solution that I used at the time.